# Plugin to Delete All Posts Monthly

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I combined 2 scripts to make a custom plugin but it automatically disables when I add this script in plugin:

```
    // do something every month
    global $wpdb; 
$evil_author = THE_ID_OF_THE_AUTHOR_WHOSE_POSTS_YOU_WANNA_BUZZIATE;
$them_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE AND post_author = $evil_author" AND post_type = "my_post_type"); // Replace my_post_type  by the post type you want

foreach ( $them_posts as $post_die ) 
{
    wp_delete_post( $post_die->ID, true ); // Bypasses Trash and deletes all the posts
}
```

Whole plugin script (both scripts) is:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name:My Custom Plugin
Description:My Custom Plugin
Version:1.0
*/

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_activation');

function my_activation() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_monthly_event' )) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(), 'monthly', 'my_monthly_event');
    }
}

add_action('my_monthly_event', 'do_this_monthly');

function do_this_monthly() {
    // do something every month
    global $wpdb; 
$evil_author = THE_ID_OF_THE_AUTHOR_WHOSE_POSTS_YOU_WANNA_BUZZIATE;
$them_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE AND post_author = $evil_author" AND post_type = "my_post_type"); // Replace my_post_type  by the post type you want

foreach ( $them_posts as $post_die ) 
{
    wp_delete_post( $post_die->ID, true ); // Bypasses Trash and deletes all the posts
}
}


// cleaning the scheduler on deactivation:

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_deactivation');

function my_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_monthly_event');
}

?>
```

Comment: If you copy paste code you generallly need to edit it. If you  put this in your code as it is, during activation, it will send errors and the plugin will not be activated. You need after editing to place it in a function that you will call with a cron job for this to work every month.

Comment: thanks for reply, this script have wp_schedule_event function, should I still use Cpanel cron job?

Comment: I'm tired i didn't saw the event :-). but$evil_author need to be an integer, did you set it in a define. Post type must be edit to other thing than my_post_type (post or page for example).

Comment: Try to debug it with wpcrontrol, but after some edit, this could work without cpanel.

Comment: your are right I already changed those in plugin but unable to activate.